# TypeScript: Use a type parameter on data-types and functions to configure mutability?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

## Intention

I'm trying to add immutability-by-default everywhere I can in my code.

I use generics because I don't want to:

1. write twice every getters (that's the critical reason, otherwise a `DeepWritable` type would do)
2. write twice every data-types
3. write more stuff to declare an immutable parameter than a mutable one,
   that's what I mean by immutable-by-default.

## Current situation

I've got a deep-readonly type:

```js
// Simplified: Only handle types used in this example
type DeepReadonly<T> = T extends number
  ? T
  : T extends ReadonlyArray<infer V>
  ? ReadonlyArray<DeepReadonly<V>>
  : { readonly [K in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[K]> };
```

And my data types can be mutable or immutable with a type parameter:

```js
type Mutability = 'const' | 'mut';

interface PlayerMut {
  life: number;
}

type Player<M extends Mutability = 'const'> = M extends 'const' ? DeepReadonly<PlayerMut> : PlayerMut;

interface GameStateMut {
  players: Player[];
}

type GameState<M extends Mutability = 'const'> = M extends 'const' ? DeepReadonly<GameStateMut> : GameStateMut;
```

I can use `GameState` as immutable (thus, by default) and `GameState<'mut'>` as mutable.

Also, `GameState<'mut'> extends GameState` is valid. So I can pass mutable states to a function expecting an immutable one (.i.e it won't modify it), but not the contrary (.i.e it would try to modify it).

So far so good...

## Problem

Then, I am trying to write a getter function which would return an immutable part of the state by default, but could return a mutable one if we wish (and providing a mutable `GameState`).

This fails:

```js
function getFirstPlayer<M extends Mutability = 'const'>(gameState: GameState<M>): Player<M> {
  // error: Type 'Readonly<PlayerMut>' is not assignable to type 'Player<M>'
  return gameState.players[0]; // dirty workaround: ...as Player<M>
}
```

In my head, this should work. But TypeScript doesn't understand it (`gameState` type in the function is equivalent to `GameState<'mut'> | GameState<'const'>`, always).

## Question

Is there a way to make the above work without resorting to `as`?

`as` works but feels like cheating. It is putting a hole in the type checking,
which is making the whole program less future-proof.

[**Typescript playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGUEsFsAcBtIDNIFMAmAuUB5AdvAJ6gAWAhnuvKqAC6GyoDOoArkxqJHnSZC6gAeZONQBQQ2AHsATrToMaAEVSpYAJVRl0UgoQA8AFQB8oALyhDoIbVSUWeVtABGqGWNCgA-JY+hsVjZ26Cya2rpEAIIyMmQG3EhuoABqxn4+YTp60bEGKmqZEQapaZ7YAN6gMlpZRKAA2gDSXDwA1qiEUkiWALrY+Ro1RUZNPaYAvgDcYhKC0nIKjKAAsqy0ZM6QiPTmoADkAMa6TLR7oAA++9Bre9Ni3LYySGQHNAAK8HFuq-LlfoiJbCOFxuabjGb0JYfL4yfTLayCWz2FZrDZbSA7CyHY6nUwWeFBZHYvAnM4+AaFPT6aGEb5rUzYGl02h3B5uZ6vUAAcREqHA61sP1Af08CBhTEZn1pMnqPTBEMU3N5-LItjhCKRIRR60222IWKOJNxuwJiOCLGJpO8oApQypPOgfIFqB+DKVjpVgrWdyQrDwB1okF0oAA5qhaAAxSAyE5M2GmzUsH5ovW7S24gAUIeVzuwDqdqtQcOMAEpJTDi8K-CBrDFZAFFXtKURqVLmcYzvxQHgpPIyEwmJAQ3gNtQ6FJFjQ9nHi3s-NVaKwZDxsx7nQA6MXSpj1AAMctANfQ0Z2AHdZK0yDIpH6sKB1w-+6AZ8s0uCxDXaBPB9R-TQ-ewnCnleeDcCGYiGkwUjUOu8BSCGWbhlGMa0HGJaTEAA)

Comment: Yes indeed. It is a known problem in TypeScript: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995